# for-of loop and process data sequentially ( even if there is async operation )

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular application, I am iterating through an array of objects and pushing newly constructed objects into an array with transformed data, getting images from API. below is the snapshot of the code.

```
 public resultObj={};
 processValues(data: MyData, profile: Profile): Observable<any[]> {
        this.processedValues = [];
        for(let value of data.values) {
            const type = value.type.toLowerCase();
            this.processImage(value).subscribe(data => {
                        this.resultObj = Object.assign({}, this.resultObj, { 'image': data });
                        this.processLabels(value, "label");
                        this.processDescriptions(value, "description");
                        this.processSelection(value, profile, 'isChecked');
                        this.resultObj = { ...this.resultObj, 'participantType': type }
                        this.resultObj = { ...this.resultObj, 'isActivated': value.activated }
                        this.c.push(this.resultObj);
                        this.resultObj = null;
                    });
        }
        return of(this.processedValues);
}
```

Here, `processImage` returns an observable wherein depending upon the value it fetches data from API or from the assets folder, if the image has to be fetched from API it takes time and the response is getting appended to the last of the '`processedValues`' list and if it is from assets folders of scaffolding it is quick and everything runs sequentially.

basically, I want to run the operation sequentially even if the image has to be fetched from API, it has to wait, complete, and then append the response and iterate next.

Comment: Did you thought of trying to use promises?

Comment: we have ample amount of RxJS operators available but anyways do you have any working example of it in the given condition